# VB.NET Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc    
@posted_xml_body xml    
AS    
INSERT INTO MyTable    
(post_datetime, post_body)    
VALUES    
(getdate(), @posted_xml_body)
```

And the following VB code:

```vb
Using aConnection As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(connectionString).ConnectionString)
    aConnection.Open()
    Dim aCommand As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("MyProc", aConnection)    
    aCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    aCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@posted_xml_body", aXMLString)

    Dim rows_affected As Integer = aCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    aCommand.Dispose()
    aConnection.Close()

    Return rows_affected

End Using
```

However, I keep receiving the following error

> "Procedure or function has too many arguments specified."

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Where is the final parenthesis in Stored Proc (after GetDate(), XML_Body) ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it in my question but it is there. VALUES
(getdate(), @posted_xml_body)

Comment: Here I utilize .ExecuteScalar to get a return value.... I can't see any else problem in your procedure.

Comment: I don't create SP in my code (I do in SQL-Mgmt) and my ones starts with a BEGIN (after the AS) end ends with END.  And I utilize the clause OUTPUT in my SP to get the number I want to receive...

Comment: My SP is created in SQL-Mgmt. I altered the procedure and code based on your suggestions but still no luck. I receive no errors and everything works as expected when traversing through the code in Debug mode locally on my machine. The error only occurs on the live site. The site only consists of a single generic handler that is responsible for calling the stored procedure and passing in the parameter. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: The problem may be related to Authorization into SQL-Server. The problem may be related to LOGIN/PASSWORD within your code and the SQL authorization to accept (or not) online requests.

Comment: And if the pointed error was solved (the parameters problems), please, vote...  :)   Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

---

You pasted wrong or is missing a ")" here

```
VALUES    
(getdate(), @posted_xml_body)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple things I would suggest.

chang the column type to nvarchar(max), select scope identity, just make sure your table as a primary key because you vb code will give you an exception trying to convert date to integer.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc    
@posted_xml_body as nvarchar(max)    
AS   
Begin 
INSERT INTO MyTable    
(post_datetime, post_body)    
VALUES    
(getdate(), @posted_xml_body);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Your Vb Code

```
Using aConnection As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(connectionString).ConnectionString)

    Dim rows_affected As Integer = 0

    Try
        aConnection.Open()

        Dim aCommand As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("MyProc", aConnection)

        aCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        aCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@posted_xml_body", aXMLString)
        rows_affected = aCommand.ExecuteScalar()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If aConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            aConnection.Close()
        End If
    End Try

    Return rows_affected

End Using
```